# what is the difference MouseInputAdapter and MouseAdapter?

Tags: java, swing, events, mouseevent

I make a method to drag any `Component` what I want even a `JFrame`

I use a `MouseInputAdapter` to make de functions

I use the **Mouse Events** and **Mouse Motion Events**

```
public static void Mover(final Component obj, final boolean info) {

        MouseInputAdapter d = new MouseInputAdapter() {
            int x, X, y, Y;

            @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    x = e.getXOnScreen();
                    X = obj.getLocation().x;
                    y = e.getYOnScreen();
                    Y = obj.getLocation().y;
                }
            }

            @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    obj.setLocation(X + (e.getXOnScreen() - x), Y + (e.getYOnScreen() - y));
                }
            }
        };
        obj.addMouseListener(d);
        obj.addMouseMotionListener(d);
    }
```

so what is the difference MouseInputAdapter and MouseAdapter?
what its better?

thanks for yours advices and answers

Answer (score 1):

> so what is the difference MouseInputAdapter

`MouseInputAdapter`, from the `javax.swing.event` package extends `MosueAdapter` and implements the `MouseInputListener`, which extends from `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener`

`MouseAdapter`, from the `java.awt.event` package implements `MouseListener`, `MouseWheelListener` and `MouseMotionListener`

I would say `MouseInputListener` doesn't support `MouseWheelListener`, so if you weren't interested in mouse wheel events, then that might be an appropriate listener, but since `MouseInputAdapter` extends from `MouseAdapter`, the whole point is mute...

> and MouseAdapter? what its better?

Either, both.

Comment: Even MouseInputListener support MouseWheelListener because extends a MouseAdapter... so it isn't a difference

Comment: @WearFox That's pretty much what I said *"the whole point is mute"*